# How Bandwidth limiting is working?

Tags: networking, bandwidth

If you see some famous FTP applications like Filezilla, they are intelligently using bandwidth resources. For example, flashget has an option to download a file at a particular bandwidth rate.

How actually are they limiting the bandwidth?

I want to implement a bandwidth limiter on my FTP code.
Any study or example code about this would be very much helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[**FileZilla** is open source](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client), you could read the code for understanding the logic.
More so, since you want to implement it.

Have not looked at the code myself, but usually most limiting algorithms are based on some [token](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket)-[bucket](http://search.cpan.org/~kappa/Algorithm-TokenBucket-0.32/lib/Algorithm/TokenBucket.pm) schemes.